# Change Metadata values in python, Detectron2

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, computer-vision, detectron

I work with Detectron for panoptic segmentation.

I would like to change the metadata values to values that I have chosen.
In particular, I would like to replace one dictionary with another dictionary that I have written.

but I got an error:

`AssertionError: Attribute 'stuff_dataset_id_to_contiguous_id' in the metadata of 'coco_2017_train_panoptic_separated' cannot be set to a different value!`

Here are the metadata I would like to change:

`MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0])` -->

```
--> out:

Metadata(evaluator_type='coco_panoptic_seg', image_root='datasets/coco/train2017',
json_file='datasets/coco/annotations/instances_train2017.json', 
name='coco_2017_train_panoptic_separated', 
panoptic_json='datasets/coco/annotations/panoptic_train2017.json' 
[...]
stuff_dataset_id_to_contiguous_id={92: 1, 93: 2, 95: 3, 100: 4, 107: 5, 109: 6,
112: 7, 118: 8, 119: 9, 122: 10, 125: 11, 128: 12, 130: 13, 133: 14, 138: 15,
141: 16, [... etc etc]
```

I would like to change **stuff_dataset_id_to_contiguous_id** to another dictionary.

What can I do? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the metadata you've registered before like this:

```
MetadataCatalog.remove("coco_2017_train_panoptic_separated")
```

You can then print all the registered metadata to check that you removed what you wanted:

```
detectron2.data.MetadataCatalog
```

And after that register new changed metadata as usual using [register_coco_instances()](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/docs/tutorials/datasets.md).

By the way, you can use the same syntax for DatasetCatalog as well:

```
DatasetCatalog.remove("coco_2017_train_panoptic_separated")
detectron2.data.DatasetCatalog
```